# Nightwatch- Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

**My e2e nightwatch tests are running perfectly fine in my MacOS whereas in my linux CI server it fails with the error -**

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdAUB.png)

**Here is my nightwatch.conf.js**

```
module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['tests/e2e/specs'],
  output_folder: 'tests/e2e/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: ['tests/e2e/custom-assertions'],
  page_objects_path: ['tests/e2e/page_objects'],

  selenium: {
    start_process: false,
    server_path: require('selenium-server').path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': require('chromedriver').path
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      selenium_port: 4444,
      selenium_host: 'localhost',
      silent: true,
      globals: {
        devServerURL: 'http://localhost:9000'
      }
    },

  chrome: {
    desiredCapabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      acceptSslCerts: true,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu', 'no-sandbox']
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried switching 'start_process" to false and running a standalone selenium server but ends up giving me the same error. Please help if anybody has any suggestions. Thanks